# How to apply custom validations into role providers in ASP.NET MVC5 with ASP.Net Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have modified UserRole entity with new properties. I need to validate user login and  generate role based menu according to those properties.

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationUserRole"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public ApplicationUserRole()
        : base()
    {
        this.ValidFrom = DateTime.Now;
        this.ValidTo = DateTime.Now;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the valid from.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The valid from.</value>
    public virtual DateTime? ValidFrom { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the valid to.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The valid to.</value>
    public virtual DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }

 }
```

if the login date not exists on the valid date range need to show user login expired message and if there is assigned multiple roles and expired one role need to hide those menu items on menu list.

Answer (score 1):

you can use custom ValidationAttribute

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


public class ValidDates : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult 
            IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = (Models.Employee)validationContext.ObjectInstance;

        DateTime _validFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(model.validFrom);
        DateTime _validTo = Convert.ToDateTime(model.ValidTo);  

        if(validation condition is true)                
               return ValidationResult.Success;             
         else
             return ValidationResult.failure;                       
        
    }
}
```

and decorate your ApplicationUserRole class with attribute ValidDates.

```
[ValidDates]
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{  //other class implementation  }
```

Comment: thanks @Laxmikant here i need to manage role based site menu also

Comment: you can visit http://techbrij.com/role-based-menu-asp-net-mvc for role based menu item.

Comment: in this article explains MVC 4 example i,m using MVC 5 Sitemap to create role based menu list